# Changing Windows Vista default keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I wanted to know how to disable the shortcut Win+Space (that brings the Vista Sidebar to the front)

I want to change this keyboard shortcut as I'm used to having Launchy set to that shortcut and Launchy won’t let me use that shortcut as it warns me that it's bound to another application.

So, does anyone know how to change the keyboard shortcuts for the sidebar? After much googling I haven't been able to find any info.

Edit: Is it possible to do this without an external program? Maybe edit the registry or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)** - a free keyboard macro program.

> AutoHotKey will also allow you to
>   override Windows default hotkeys.

Tutorial: [Windows Hot Keys with AutoHotKey](http://blogs.msdn.com/noahc/archive/2008/06/14/windows-hot-keys-with-autohotkey.aspx) (incl. configuration file)